# Why mouse pointer is changing to arrow and not triggering click event over the icon?

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net-core, cursor

I am using an icon in my MVC Core application. when I hover over the icon it should show tooltip and let me to trigger an event on click. I set the css property cursor to "pointer".

In my case, when I hover the mouse over the icon, the cursor is rapidly changing from pointer to arrow continuously. As it is changing into an arrow, I am not able to trigger click event.

I am completely confused.

```
<i class='fa fa-plus-square fa-lg displaytooltip' id='idAdd'  title='' style = 'cursor:pointer;color:orange' onclick=Add();></i >
```

[SampleVideo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1mq9.gif)

Answer (score 0):

you need to call a function in "" or '' **Quotation mar**k

```
    <button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

you did not add function in "" or  ''  **Quotation mark** that why it's not working also

---

there not need to add semicolon(;) for closing your function

```
<i class='fa fa-plus-square fa-lg displaytooltip' id='idAdd'  title='' style = 'cursor:pointer;color:orange' onclick="Add()"></i >
```

```js
function Add(){
alert("call add function");
}
```

```html
<i class='fa fa-plus-square fa-lg displaytooltip' id='idAdd'  title='' style = 'cursor:pointer;color:orange' onclick="Add()">YOUR ICON </i >
```

Comment: Hi @shakil, Actually, that click event is working sometimes. I can't predict the error occurrence.   when I hover over the <i> tag, cursor pointer is toggling from pointer to arrow and arrow to pointer continuously. if it is in arrow, I can't click that icon. I tested by running the code locally, It is working fine. If I deploy in IIS , then i am facing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, as long as you don’t disable the element's click event and add the `onclick` event in detail, no matter what state your mouse hover over is, you can still trigger the click event.

The premise is that you must ensure that you `click on the element itself`, and not elsewhere.

```
 @{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}   
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script>  
    function Add() {
        alert("clicked!");
    }
</script>
<i class='fa fa-plus-square fa-lg displaytooltip' id='idAdd' title='click me'
   style='cursor:pointer;color:orange' onclick=Add();>
</i>
```

This is the test result:
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot @Yongqing You, But my issue is slightly different. I have attached a sample video in my question. Please look into that video, you will get a clear picture of my request.

Comment: @YuvarajT, there is indeed a problem in the video, you should provide us with more relevant code for our reference.

Answer (score -1):

In my case (using material ui in react js) and this simple line of code saved me.
style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}

e.g

```
<Box onClick={() => openPolicyModal()} style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}>
```